# slickgrid modal not aligning proper

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

**Slickgrid columns are**

```
var columns = [
                    {id: 'validity', name: gettextCatalog.getString('Valid'), field: 'validity', width: 80, formatter: validityFormatter},
                    {id: 'mid', name: gettextCatalog.getString('MID'), field: 'mid',  width: 70, formatter: midFormatter, asyncPostRender: editAttributes, editor: editors.inputTextBox},
                    {id: 'merchantName', name: gettextCatalog.getString('Merchant Name'), field: 'merchantName', width: 100, formatter: nameFormatter},
                    {id: 'status', name: gettextCatalog.getString('Status'), field: 'status',  width: 40, formatter: statusFormatter, asyncPostRender: editAttributes, editor: editors.inputTextBox},
                    {id: 'orderId', name: gettextCatalog.getString('OrderId'), field: 'orderId',  width: 40, formatter: orderFormatter, asyncPostRender: editOrderAttributes},
                    {id: 'amount', name: gettextCatalog.getString('Amount'), field: 'amount', width: 75, formatter: amountFormatter, asyncPostRender: editAttributes, editor: editors.inputTextBox},
                    {id: 'Action', name: gettextCatalog.getString('Delete'), field: 'action', width: 50, formatter: actionsFormatter}
                ];
```

i have also used `forceFitColumns: true` in column option, but the grid is not properly getting aligned.

Comment: you'll need to give more details. a screenshot of the problem would be great.

Comment: thanks @ben-mcintyre. Can u help me on how to attach the screenshot here. I dont find any option.

Comment: edit your question. then in the bar along the top of the editing area, there is an icon with some triangles and a circle (mountains and a sun). Use that to add an image.